# Why is this funny?

Tags: puns, jokes

A forum says that most Japanese will find this funny but I don't get it. Can anyone explain?

[image]

([source](http://livedoor.4.blogimg.jp/himasoku123/imgs/9/1/91e42d57.jpg))

> おもさを
>   たいせきで
>   わるんだなあ
>   みつど

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Because it is like a famous Japanese poet 相田{あいだ}みつを's style of writing.

He often used the word だなぁ. And おもさをたいせきでわる is not funny in itself, it is a mathematical sentence.

I give a little explanation of this funny. 相田みつを mainly wrote about the importance of life, human life, encouragement and love for afflicted people in his poems with easy words. And だなぁ have soft note. while おもさをたいせきでわる is just a mathematical equation and we usually don't attach だなぁ to it. So I think its contradistinction would be funny and the pun which naruto noticed is also the cause.

Some of his poems are [here](http://iyashitour.com/meigen/greatman/aidamitsuo).

Comment: JFYI おもさをたいせきでわる ("weight is devided by volume") is a definition of みつど (密度, density) at the end. So this is a pun on みつを and みつど.

Comment: Great answer... I could read it and I suspected it was some kind of parody of poetry, but I didn't know whose poetry it was alluding to...

Comment: it's so funny, I laughed so hard because even after reading your answer I still don't get which part is funny. T.T

Comment: @Kakashi  I give a little explanation of this funny. I wish it helps you.

Comment: あの、念のためですけど、意味の無い数式を詩的に書いてるということ自体でそんなに面白いのではなくて、最後が「みつど」なのが面白いんだとおもうのですが、そこは大丈夫ですよね？

Comment: 私は、ふたつが合わさって面白いと思います。「おもさをたいせきでわる　みつど」、より「おもさをたいせきでわるんだなぁ　みつど」の方が断然面白いと感じます。「だなぁ」と「みつど」がキーですね。

Answer (score 5):

I read “おもさをたいせきでわるんだなあ　みつど” by verbatim as;
重さを体積で割るんだなあ、密度 – It’ s weight divided by volume, density, isn’t it.

Though I’m not good at mathematics, the density of material can be measured in proportion of weight and volume.

“みつど- ” can be a play of word of 密度- density with the name of (相田)みつお, a famous author of aphoristic poems but I’m not sure of it.