# Why is "学校があるからお休みが染みるんだなあ" a poem?

Tags: manga, culture

I was reading a [web manga](https://www.pixiv.net/artworks/80391328), and came across this panel:

[image]

The spring break (春休み) has just started for this character, and apparently she refers to the following as poem (as in 詩を詠んでしまった):

> 学校が
>
> あるから
>
> お休みが
>
> 染みるん
>
> だなあ

My translation:

> It's because school days exist that holidays make a deep impression on you.

Which I understand.

But from the way the lines are broken, I can't see a 5-7-5 syllable pattern, so I'm not sure what distinguishing feature this thing has that makes it a "poem". It could have been some random text that someone has written and signed with their name, right?

Is there some kind of rhythm to read this that makes this particularly poetic or something?

Comment: This might help: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40913/9831

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_verse  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prose_poetry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, it is a [free verse poem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_verse). There is no rhythm. For me, this reminds me of [相田みつを](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%9B%B8%E7%94%B0%E3%81%BF%E3%81%A4%E3%82%92) poems. See [these images](https://matome.naver.jp/odai/2136756405322359501) and see if you agree with me!